# Add one line to all found files

Tags: find, exec

My original working directory hierarchy:

```
$ find
.
./usr1
./usr1/.vimrc
./usr2
./usr2/.vimrc
```

I want to add one line -- "set number" -- to all *.vimrc* files. So I ran this command:

```
find -name ".vimrc" -exec echo "set number" >> {} \;
```

But, all *.vimrc* files stay the same, and there is a new-created *{}* file in my working directory:

```
$ find
.
./usr1
./usr1/.vimrc
./{}
./usr2
./usr2/.vimrc
```

What is wrong? How can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect output of command with `-exec`, It is better to execute shell command ; Try the following syntax in your case:

```
find -name ".vimrc" -exec sh -c 'echo "set number" >> {}' \;
```

This will work as expected.